# List reorganization

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists (finally for the first one it is a list of tuples):

```
>>> liste_1 = [("aaaa 1", "blabla1"), ("aaaa 2", "blabla2"), ("aaaa 3", "blabla3"), ("aaaa 4", "blabla4"), ("aaaa 5", "blabla5"), ("aaaa 6", "blabla6"), ("aaaa 7", "blabla7")]

>>> liste_2 = ["aaaa 1", "aaaa 6", "aaaa 2", "aaaa 3", "aaaa 4", "aaaa 7", "aaaa 5"]
```

I would compare the elements to the index 0 contained in each tuple of the list liste_1 with each element of the list liste_2 and if a difference is found I would like that afterwards a new list can contain the elements of the list list_1 reorganized as this:

```
>>> nouvelle_liste = ["blabla1", "blabla6", "blabla2", "blabla3", "blabla4", "blabla7", "blabla5"]
```

Can you help me find a solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There's a duplicate for this around here somewhere, but here's a hint: use `sorted` with a `key` argument involving `liste_2.index`.

Comment: @chepner I don't think OP wants to sort anything, but replace with the values from `liste_1`. (Not saying that it's not a duplicate of _some_ question, but not that one)

Comment: Convert your `liste_1` to a `dict`, i.e. `liste_1_as_dict = dict(liste_1)`, then look up the value in a list comprehension: `nouvelle_liste = [liste_1_as_dict[x] for x in liste_2]`

Comment: Yes I would like to replace the elements "blabla1", "blabla2", "blabla3", "blabla4", ... in a new list.

Comment: Don't think of it as reorganizing / filtering / sorting list1 by the elements in list2, if they are in that list, and then removing the first part, but of replacing the elements in list2 with the corresponding values in list1; faster and easier that way, see previous comment.

Comment: @tobias_k Too much Haskell; a single O(n) conversion to a dict to allow multiple O(1) lookups is viable. I'll re-open so you can post that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!, the dictionary solution works very well.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in a single line:

```
nouvelle_liste = [arrimage[i2] for arrimage in [dict(liste_1)] for i2 in liste_2]
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Afterwards is it possible to add all the elements contained in nouvelle_liste ( --> 'blabla1'+'blabla6'+'blabla2'+'blabla3'+'blabla4'+'blabla7'+'blabla5' ) to obtain (in a simple way) : 'blabla1blabla6blabla2blabla3blabla4blabla7blabla5' ?

Comment: `"".join(nouvelle_liste)`

Comment: What's wrong with defining the `dict` outside of the list comprehension?